# Fastest way to filter a dictionary and "simplify" its values in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, sorteddictionary

In C#, given a SortedDictionary, I need to filter on its keys and then "simplify" its values. This is best explained by the following MWE, which does exactly what I want

```
static void Main()
{
    var lowerBound = new DateTime(2018, 01, 02);
    var upperBound = new DateTime(2018, 01, 04);

    var myInput = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, SimpleItem>();

    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.1, item2 = 2.1 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 02), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.2, item2 = 2.2 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 03), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.3, item2 = 2.3 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 04), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.4, item2 = 2.4 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 05), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.5, item2 = 2.5 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 06), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.6, item2 = 2.6 });
    myInput.Add(new DateTime(2018, 01, 07), new SimpleItem { item1 = 1.7, item2 = 2.7 });

    var q = myInput.Where(x => x.Key >= lowerBound && x.Key <= upperBound);

    Dictionary<DateTime, double> d = 
                  q.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.item1);

    SortedDictionary<DateTime, double> myOutput = 
                  new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>(d);

    int wait = 0;
}

class SimpleItem
{
    public double item1 { get; set; }
    public double item2 { get; set; }
}
```

By profiling my actual code (not this MWE), it is quite clear that `ToDictionary` is *extremely* slow (all the other parts seem ok). So I m simply asking for another way (hopefully the fastest) to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: How many elements do you have and what does "extremely slow" mean?

Comment: If you don't need to *modify* the resulting dictionary (just read values from it), my suggestion would be to create a wrapper around it: A new class which implements `IDictionary<DateTime, double>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>` (or whatever parts of `SortedDictionary` you actually need) which "filters" requests for data and, if inside the requested range, forwards them to the "real" dictionary.

Comment: Join Heinzi's suggestion with immutable dictionaríes / wrappers and you are set!

Comment: Is this MWE a true representation of the data that will be used? What does a "simple item" represent?
The reason I ask this is that the "simple item" assignments take about twice as much memory as the Date they are representing. Have you tried this using a float instead of double?

Comment: By extremely slow, i mean that a profile shows that 80-90% of time is spent in ToDictionary - and this is by running a program that does many other things. SimpleItem is just to get to a MWE, in reality I have a simple calss with some doubles, some strings and so on but at the end i just need to get one of the doubles.

Comment: @Giulio That's not actually telling you anything.  You need to remember that most LINQ operations return queries, not the results of those queries.  `var q = myInput.Where(x => x.Key >= lowerBound && x.Key <= upperBound);` doesn't *do* anything, it just defines what *will* happen when `q` is actually iterated.  Your `ToDictionary` call then actually *executes* that query to get its result.

Comment: @Servy thx - i ll keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your filtering of the `SortedDictionary` doesn't take advantage of the fact that it is sorted. Since `ICollection` (and C# generic collections in general) don't implement any sort of efficient splice operation, lookup is your best bet.

Turning your filter around, you get:

```
var q = Enumerable.Range(0, (Int32)(upperBound - lowerBound).TotalDays+1).Select(n => new { Key = lowerBound.AddDays(n), Item = myInput[lowerBound.AddDays(n)].item1 });

var myOutput = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>();

foreach (var pair in q)
    myOutput.Add(pair.Key, pair.Item);
```

The other methods all average about the same time. Using a very small separation in `lowerBound` and `upperBound` results in thousands of times faster performance. Even using a two year span results in hundreds of times faster performance when `myInput` contains 2 million entries.

Note that the scope of speedup really depends on how many entries are in the `SortedList`, a small list will not show much difference in performance.

Comment: thx a lot - i quickly tried it and it seems to give a significant speed up. Just to be sure: i think you need (upperBound - lowerBound).TotalDays + 1 to achieve exactly the same behavior as my code, do i understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The [SortedDictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sorteddictionary.cs,31) constructor simply iterates over the input dictionary's KeyValuePair objects and calls `.Add()`:

```
public SortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer) {
    if( dictionary == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.dictionary);
    }

    _set = new TreeSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(new KeyValuePairComparer(comparer));

    foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in dictionary) {
        _set.Add(pair);
    }            
}
```

This means that you don't gain anything by creating the intermediate dictionary. You could write a query to filter and select the values you want and add them to the dictionary through the ICollection.Add method :

```
var q = myInput.Where(x => x.Key >= lowerBound && x.Key <= upperBound)
               .Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>(x.Key,x.Value.item1));

var myOutput = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>();    
var coll=(ICollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>>)myOutput;

foreach(var pair in q)
{
  coll.Add(pair);
}
```

SortedDictionary isn't thread-safe for writing *or* enumerating, which means you can't use PLINQ to speed up filtering the source dictionary or creating the new one.

Comment: I wonder why C# implements the `ICollection.Add` explicitly. My timing seems to show this isn't any faster than `ToDictionary`/`new SortedDictionary` and is often fractionally slower.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: thanks - actually I tried it and i saw no speed up. Note that from my profiling it looks that the bottleneck of that code is the call to ToDictionary. The other calls (Where and SortedDictionary ctor) look almost for free

Comment: @Giulio which this answer *eliminates*. The loop is essentially the same code as the constructor. If you didn't see any speedup, it's not `ToDictionary` that causes the delay, it's the filtering. You can't speed *that* up because enumerating a `SortedDictionary` isn't thread safe. Otherwise you could write `myInput.AsParallel()` to parallelize it.

Comment: @Giulio without actual data sizes and performance data it's impossible to answer your question. If you want to parallelize LINQ queries, don't use a SortedDictionary or Dictionary. `SimpleItem` is a class which means only a reference to the actual object is stored in the dictionary. You could store the items in an array which *can* be parallelized and then add them to the SortedDictionary paying only for the extra references. Essentially you'd use `SortedDictionary` as an index

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos it s basically sure that the bottleneck is ToDictionary. The profiler indicates that. Let me try to profile your code and profile again: I guess the bottleneck there will be Select?

Comment: @Guilio Yes. `ToDictionary()` [does the same thing](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,964) as SortedDictionary's constructor. It forces the `IEnumerable<>` to execute and adds the results to a dictionary. You are probably seeing the effects of the query, not actually adding elements to the dictionary.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I confirm that your solution does not give a speed up. I profiled again and now I can tell you that all the time is spent in IEnumerator.MoveNext()